# Camera2 Api: LegacyCameraDevice_nativeGetSurfaceId: Could not retrieve native Surface from surface

Tags: android, android-camera2

I was trying to use the `Camera2` API of Android. The front camera is working fine, but when it comes to using the back/rear camera, this error occurs:

```
LegacyCameraDevice_nativeGetSurfaceId: Could not retrieve native Surface from surface.
```

This problem occurs after I click the button to take a picture. The capture callback is successful, but I get no image in `onImageAvailable()`.

I followed the tutorial of https://web.archive.org/web/20161011160303/https://inducesmile.com/android/android-camera2-api-example-tutorial/ . I do not have any idea on how to proceed with the error that I am facing right now.

Here is the code used in capturing the image:

```
private void takePicture() {
    if (mCameraDevice == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        CameraManager mManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

        try {
            CameraCharacteristics mCharacteristics = mManager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraDevice.getId());
            Size[] jpegSizes = null;

            if (mCharacteristics != null) {
                jpegSizes = mCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
            }

            int width = 640;
            int height = 480;

            for(int x = 0; x < jpegSizes.length; x++) {
                Log.wtf("jpegSizes", String.valueOf(jpegSizes[x]));
            }

            if (jpegSizes != null && jpegSizes.length > 0) {
                width = jpegSizes[4].getWidth();
                height = jpegSizes[4].getHeight();
            }

            final ImageReader mReader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);

            List<Surface> mOutputSurface = new ArrayList<>(2);
            mOutputSurface.add(mReader.getSurface());
            mOutputSurface.add(new Surface(mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture()));

            final CaptureRequest.Builder mCaptureBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            mCaptureBuilder.addTarget(mReader.getSurface());
            mCaptureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);

            int mRotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            int jpegOrientation = (ORIENTATIONS.get(mRotation) + mSensorOrientation + 270) % 360;

            if(cameraId.equals("0")) {
                mCaptureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(mRotation));
            } else {
                if(extras.getString("orient").equals("landscape")) {
                    mCaptureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(mRotation));
                } else {
                    mCaptureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, jpegOrientation);
                }
            }

            final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                    if(mImage == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(StartCameraActivity.this, "Capturing Image Failed, Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.wtf("onCaptureComplete", "Image not Available");
                    } else {
                        Log.wtf("onCaptureComplete", "Image Available");
                    }
                    //createCameraPreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCaptureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull CaptureFailure failure) {
                    super.onCaptureFailed(session, request, failure);
                    Log.wtf("FAILED", failure.toString());
                }
            };

            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(mOutputSurface, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    Log.wtf("onConfigured", "succes");
                    try {
                        session.capture(mCaptureBuilder.build(), captureListener, mBackgroundHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    Log.wtf("onConfigureFailed", "failed");
                }
            }, mBackgroundHandler);

            mReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(final ImageReader reader) {
                    mImage = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                    Log.wtf("imageAvail", "OnImageAvailable");

                    StartCameraActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (mImage == null) {
                                return;
                            }
                            final Image.Plane[] planes = mImage.getPlanes();
                            final ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
                            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                            buffer.get(bytes);
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

                            mTextureView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            if(cameraId.equals("0")) {
                                screenshotHolder.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            } else {
                                screenshotHolder.setImageBitmap(flip(bitmap, mImage.getWidth(), mImage.getHeight()));
                            }
                            new RenderPicture(StartCameraActivity.this).execute();

                            if (mImage != null) {
                                mImage.close();
                            }
                            if(mReader != null) {
                                mReader.close();
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
            }, mBackgroundHandler);


        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By using camera2 API on LEGACY device you expose yourself to an extra kind of platform bugs and tiny incompatibilities. If your code has an `else` branch that falls back to the old API, you should choose it when you detect they your camera2 is but a wrapper. Note that this check must be made for front and rear cameras separately

Comment: Very likely, your problem is that you change the jpeg size for a camera that already started preview session. To handle this change, the camera2 LEGACY wrapper must stop and restart the preview session, and at that very moment, the capture request fails to find a running session.

Answer (score 4):

Your ImageReader is a local variable in takePicture, and doesn't look like it's stored anywhere in the parent class.  It's likely being garbage collected immediately or soon after takePicture exits, so when the camera tries to set itself up, the Surface reports as being abandoned.

A Surface is like a weak reference and won't keep the ImageReader alive by itself. Store it in the parent class like you do with the camera device.

Comment: For me it happens only for legacy camera devices when using camera2 api and my activity stops and destroys, I have only preview surface, there is no image reader surface and so on